# Find what process is on the other end of a pipe

Tags: linux, pipe

I'm trying to trace some odd behavior of a few processes and ran into a point I'm not sure how to trace past.  The hung process, which I attached to using `strace -p` showed this:

```
Process 7926 attached - interrupt to quit
read(3,
```

Okay, so it's waiting for input on fd 3, so I went to check what it is:

```
$ ls -l /proc/7926/fd/3
lr-x------ 1 user grp 64 Mar 15 10:41 /proc/7926/fd/3 -> pipe:[20043922]
```

Okay, so it's a pipe... now the question -- who is the writer of this pipe? I recall that on Linux there is a special feature for unix domain sockets where you can request a file path that starts with a NUL byte to access the "abstract socket namespace" (mentioned here: http://tkhanson.net/cgit.cgi/misc.git/plain/unixdomain/Unix_domain_sockets.html). I'm not sure if there's something similar for pipes that I could take advantage of, but I haven't found anything.

I was hoping a tool like `fuser` or `lsof` might help, but I haven't gotten anywhere.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The symlink contents "pipe:[20043922]" are a unique ID; the other end of the pipe will have a matching ID.

```
(find /proc -type l | xargs ls -l | fgrep 'pipe:[20043922]') 2>/dev/null
```

should show you both ends of the pipe.

Comment: Good thinking, thanks! While investigating I also came across this thread here http://serverfault.com/questions/48330/how-can-i-get-more-info-on-open-pipes-show-in-proc-in-linux so I thought I'd drop the link here too just ffr for others too.

Comment: Why use `find`?  `ls -l /proc/*/fd/* | fgrep 'pipe :[20043922]'` is simpler.

Comment: @DevenT.Corzine Wildcard expansion might result in a line that is too long, either for the shell or the operating system.

Comment: Oh, good point.  If the wildcard expansion is too much, your `find` command will still work.

Comment: `find` can do the filtering `find /proc -lname 'pipe:\[20043922]' 2>/dev/null`.

Answer (score 6):

You can get the list of processes using the pipe by using `lsof` command:

`lsof | grep 'FIFO.*20043922'`

The output will show the readers (in the FD column with entries like 1r) and writers (same columns with entries like 2w).

Comment: This takes long time to get processed, the answer that traverses `/proc` with `find` is much faster *(or the answer with `px` for that matter, even though apparently `px` makes use of `lsof` as well — it mentions `lsof` in the output. Presumably it uses some args to narrow down the amount of processing `lsof` has to do)*.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use [px](https://github.com/walles/px).

Disclaimer: I wrote it, so of course I'm recommending it.

`px` will tell you which other processes yours is talking to, `sudo px 7926` would have gotten you the answer.

Example output (not your PID obviously, but still), scroll to the bottom for pipes tracing:

```
~ $ sudo px 76572
cat

kernel(0)               root
  launchd(1)            root
    iTerm2(39341)       johan
      iTerm2(39343)     johan
        login(39344)    root
          -fish(39346)  johan
----------> cat(76572)  johan

14.62s ago cat was started, at 2020-09-12T16:20:12+02:00.

Other processes started close to cat(76572):
  CoreServices/mdworker_shared(76468) was started 4m32s before cat(76572)
  CoreServices/mdworker_shared(76475) was started 4m02s before cat(76572)
  CoreServices/mdworker_shared(76541) was started 1m55s before cat(76572)
  cat(76573) was started just after cat(76572)
  sudo px(76583) was started 14.0s after cat(76572)

Users logged in when cat(76572) started:
  johan

2020-09-12T16:20:26.739132: Now invoking lsof, this can take over a minute on a big system...
2020-09-12T16:20:27.052847: lsof done, proceeding.

Others sharing this process' working directory (/Users/johan)
  cat(76573)
  -fish(39346)
  iTerm2(39343)
  login(39344)
  sudo px(76583)

File descriptors:
  stdin : [CHR] /dev/ttys000
  stdout: [PIPE] -> cat(76573) (0x204c1334a30aa50d)
  stderr: [CHR] /dev/ttys000

Network connections:

Inter Process Communication:
  cat(76573): [PIPE] ->0x204c1334a30aa50d

For a list of all open files, do "sudo lsof -p 76572", or "sudo watch lsof -p 76572" for a live view.
~ $
```

Comment: Great tool! And [Debian also provides it via the *px* package](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=px&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all) (`sudo apt install px`).